# mongoose findOne sometimes returns null sometimes returns the right result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have one password in my MongoDB atlas database and that's 1992.
When starting my node server and entering the 1992, there's an estimate chance of 20% that it will find something. When restarting the server it mostly doesn't find an entry doesn't matter how often I enter the password.
Restart again and boom it finds an entry. Restart again. Nothing. Why does this happen? Please help me

```
router.post('/checkListPassword', (req,res) => {
  const {password} = req.body;
  PW.findOne({id: password}).then((result) => console.log(result))
});
```

Comment: Might be issue with connecting DB. Try to connect DB first then do the query.

Comment: Can you also share how have you connected to mongo?

Comment: ```const msgdbRoute = 
  'mongodb+srv://USER:PW@nodecluster-cvkjt.mongodb.net/message?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(pwdbRoute, {useNewUrlParser:true});
let pwdb = mongoose.connection;
pwdb.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the pwdatabase'));
pwdb.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'pwMongoDB connection error:'));
```

Comment: now changed to this and it works:
```
router.post('/checkListPassword', (req,res) => {
  const {password} = req.body;
  const pwdbRoute = 
  'mongodb+srv://USER:PW@nodecluster-cvkjt.mongodb.net/pw?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
  mongoose.connect(pwdbRoute, {useNewUrlParser:true});
  let pwdb = mongoose.connection;
  pwdb.once('open', () => {
    console.log('connected to pwDatabase');
    PW.findOne({id: password}).then((result) => console.log(result))
    pwdb.close();
    console.log('closed pwDB connection');
  });
});```